# Is there a way to change preview image of website social share links?

Tags: html, web, dns, cloudflare

I host my static website on Google Storage with a domain bought from Godaddy and changed the nameservers to CloudFlare for SSL security. When I attempt to share my website on social media the image preview that is shown is displayed below. My Meta tags in my website head are also displayed below. I have Googled, spoken to Godaddy, checked documentation on CloudFlare there is no clear solution to my share image preview problem.

HTML Header Code

```html
<!--  Meta  -->
<!-- Primary Meta Tags -->
<title>Virtual HBCU</title>
<meta name="title" content="Virtual HBCU">
<meta name="description" content="Explore virtual HBCU tours and exhibits.">

<!-- Open Graph / Facebook -->
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://virtualhbcu.com">
<meta property="og:title" content="Virtual HBCU">
<meta property="og:description" content="Explore virtual HBCU tours and exhibits.">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://virtual-hbcu.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/OG+VIRTUAL+HBCU.png">

<!-- Twitter -->
<meta property="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta property="twitter:url" content="https://virtualhbcu.com">
<meta property="twitter:title" content="Virtual HBCU">
<meta property="twitter:description" content="Explore virtual HBCU tours and exhibits.">
<meta property="twitter:image" content="https://virtual-hbcu.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/OG+VIRTUAL+HBCU.png">
```

What is being shown on social sharing...

[image: URL Shortener error]

How do I resolve to preview image issue on social sharing links?

The image preview should look like this...

[image: Desired Image]

Edit:
Permanent redirect...
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I've swapped the domain to `example.com` to make this answer a bit more general - switch it back when testing and implementing.*

The issue here is that `www.example.com` points to your actual website, but `example.com` (without `www.`) redirects you to another site - in this case, a 404 from a URL shortener. Even though on social media the link you're entering starts with `www.`, the `<meta>` `og:url` and `twitter:url` properties tell the social networks to ignore that, and use the non-`www.` version specified instead.

Check your DNS entry for the `www` name in Cloudflare - something is misconfigured somewhere, perhaps a typo in the IP. It could also be something misconfigured at your hosting provider.

You should also update the `<meta>` tags to use URLs consistent with where the page is actually being displayed.

You could add a Page Rule in Cloudflare to redirect the non-`www.` version of your site to the `www.` version.
If the URL matches `example.com/*`, use a Forwarding URL with 301 Permanent Redirect to `https://www.example.com/$1`, where `$1` is the first appearance of `*` in your rule.